# SE site for sign languages

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a SE-site where questions about sign languages are considered on-topic? Or has there ever been a denied/failed Area 51 proposal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It might depend on what type of question about sign language you have, but in some form it would seem to be on topic on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/). From the Help Center [list of topics](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions about learning or teaching techniques regarding any *human* language, including dead, unspoken and constructed languages.

As sign languages are human languages, they should fall under that category. Moreover, there is already a [sign language tag](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sign-language) with seven questions.

The above should probably be suitable for questions mostly relating to learning/teaching a sign language. Other types of questions might be on topic on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sign-languages). The Help Center [list of topics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there explicitly includes sign languages:

> Sign Languages and writing systems

The [sign languages tag](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sign-languages) there has 47 questions.

Questions about sign language as they relate to a particular topic would probably also be on topic on a site that deals with that particular topic.  For example if you had a question about using sign language at work, I would imagine that it might be on topic on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).